# How can we automate Linux cut command using bash

Tags: linux, bash, unix

Let suppose I have a text file having 4 column and I have to cut every single column and save it into another text file. Manually I can do this by the following Linux command but I want to automate this process using bash script. Can someone help me with this

```
cut  textfile.txt | cut -d ":" -f1 > output1.txt

cut  textfile.txt | cut -d ":" -f2 > output2.txt

cut  textfile.txt | cut -d ":" -f3 > output3.txt

cut  textfile.txt | cut -d ":" -f4 > output4.txt
```

Textfile.txt

```
"text1":"text2":"text3":"text4"
"text1":"text2":"text3":"text4"
"text1":"text2":"text3":"text4"
"text1":"text2":"text3":"text4"
"text1":"text2":"text3":"text4"
"text1":"text2":"text3":"text4"
"text1":"text2":"text3":"text4"
"text1":"text2":"text3":"text4"
"text1":"text2":"text3":"text4"
```

col 1 should store in output1.txt

```
text1;
text1;
text1;
text1;
text1;
text1;
```

col 2 should store in output2.txt

```
text2;
text2;
text2;
text2;
text2;
text2;
```

col 3 should store in output3.txt

```
text3;
text3;
text3;
text3;
text3;
text3;
```

col 4 should store in output4.txt

```
text4;
text4;
text4;
text4;
text4;
text4;
```

Comment: What do you mean by automate? If the number of columns is fixed, I'd turn this into an `awk` script that reads the input once and writes to four separate files.

Comment: No of columns are not fixed

Comment: Just put your command line commands in a text file and execute it.

Comment: I also want to remove double quotes from the text and put semi colon at the end for example: "text1" to text1; for all the columns @Red Cricket

Comment: @FahadHaroon you should make your question include **all** your requirements, nobody would like answer ping-pong questions

Comment: @Fahad use sed to remove the "'s and append the ";".  `... | sed -e's/"//g' | sed -e's/$/;/g' > …`

Comment: @RedCricket, there's no reason to use a separate `sed` command for each of those operations. `sed -e 'op1' -e 'op2'` runs both operations in one instance -- though of course, `awk` can also do all the work of `sed`, so an extra `sed` stage in combination with either preexisting answer is pointless.

Comment: Waitaminute -- reading the question history, it **explicitly asked for** output to contain the quotes, such that both extant answers look like they got it right the first time. Changing specifications in such a way as to invalidate existing answers is not welcome here.

Comment: Yes it works @Red Cricket thanx (y)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This awk one-liner works for the given example input:

```
awk -F':' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)print $i>"output"i".txt"}' file
```

After executing this command, you will get output1-4.txt as result.

OP commented:

> No of columns are not fixed

If your input file has many columns, you need to close the file and append text into the file:

```
awk -F':' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){f="output"i".txt;print $i>>f;close(f)}' file
```

Comment: I have edited my question this is the output what I want @Kent

Answer (score 1):

Given:

```
$ cat file
"text1":"text2":"text3":"text4"
"text1":"text2":"text3":"text4"
"text1":"text2":"text3":"text4"
```

You can use `awk` to turn that into columns:

```
$ awk -F: '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) print $i>"file" i ".txt"}' file
```

You can remove the quote characters and add `;` with:

```
awk -F: '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
                gsub(/"/,"",$i) 
                print $i ";">"file" i ".txt"}}' file
```

Result:

```
$ cat file{1..4}.txt
text1;
text1;
text1;
text2;
text2;
text2;
text3;
text3;
text3;
text4;
text4;
text4;
```

Comment: @dwag can we remove double quotes and put semi colon at the end by using the awk command you mentioned